# Why LIKE filter is not hit the index when the query starts with '\2\'

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have the SQL statement like this, the current problem I have is that it didn't hit the index I have created on [Path] column whenever the filter value starts with `\`

```
Select * from [org].[H_D] hd where [Path] like '\2\%'
```

When I removed the `\` (e.g. `Select * from [org].[H_D] hd where [Path] like '2\%'`) then it works as I expected.

I used this SQL statement to create index on [Path] column

```
create index t1i1 on [org].[H_D]([Path] ASC)
```

The profiles of both queries are here 
[image: without "\"]
[image: without "\"]

Comment: Presumably the index isn't covering and it has different cardinality estimates for the different literals.

Comment: What happens when you use "Select [Path] from [org].[H_D] hd where [Path] like '\2\%'"?  Does it always use the index then?

Comment: @MJH No, In the Execution Plan, It showed "Cluster Index Scan" but when I tried with "Select [Path] from [org].[H_D] hd where [Path] like '2\%'" then it showed "Index seek"

Comment: As @Martin Smith said, the index is not covering and the cardinality estimates are different for the literals i.e. the query can not use the index alone, it has to "look up" the extra values from the clustered index.

Comment: @MartinSmith, When I tried with this query "Select * from [org].[H_D] hd where [Path] like '\123\%'", this one hit the index! Can you explain more?

Comment: @MJH, this one "Select * from [org].[H_D] hd where [Path] like '\123\%'" hit the index. Do you have any suggestion to deal with this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want a Clustered index scan instead of an index seek with CI lookup?  I would imagine that would be slower, is it?

Comment: How many rows are hit with `2\%` versus `\2\%` versus `\123\%`? The optimizer uses histogram statistics to estimate whether a seek or a scan would be better. If there are few to no rows beginning with ``\``, a seek followed by a clustered index lookup would be obvious, whereas this easily gets too expensive (as far as the optimizer is concerned) for many matching rows.

Comment: mouse over the arrow in the query 1 plan. What is the estimated rows? How many rows are there in the whole table? The tipping point at which it can turn from seek + lookups to scan can be just a percent or so dependant on how wide the table is

Comment: @JeroenMostert, with `\2\%` there were around 5000 records, the other two just around dozens of records

Comment: There you go. The threshold the optimizer has for switching to a scan is pretty low (sometimes uncomfortably so). Even though this is probably much worse than getting the rows from the index, then seeking those 5000 rows in the clustered index, it still prefers a table scan. There are ways around this -- using a parameter and an `OPTIMIZE FOR` hint, creating filtered statistics or a filtered index, or applying a `FORCESEEK` hint (the latter should be used as a last resort though, since it will give horrible results if the seek ever really *is* expensive).

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you're correct, I tried to apply the same context but in the difference column and in that column there are no "\" character, It leads to the same result. Thanks a lot!